# How are environment variables defined in a Gnome terminal session?

Tags: terminal, gnome, desktop-environment

I'm trying to understand a user login process on Centos 7 and I've gotten a bit confused trying to figure out when/how a Gnome terminal session defines environment variables (Gnome 3.14.4).

As near as I can tell.... a Gnome terminal will only define environment variables from the /etc/profile, ~/.profile, or ~/.bash_profile if the variables were exported in those scripts.

If they aren't exported then they don't appear in the output of either the set or printenv commands. The /etc/environment file is the exception (but it's not a shell login script).

The only thing I've found that looks like it would do this is the **/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common** file when it sources the ~/.profile login script... But that's just a single login script and doesn't explain why exported variables in /etc/profile & ~!/.bash_profile are being displayed in set.

```
[ -r $HOME/.profile ] && . $HOME/.profile
```

If this reads the variables in the ~/.profile script... How are the variables being read for /etc/profile & ~/.bash_profile? If it matters.... I haven't selected "run command as login script"

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Gnome Terminal runs bash (the GNU Bourne Again SHell) by default.

Actually it probably runs whatever shell is specified for your account in /etc/passwd

On startup bash goes through ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile, that's why those variables get set.

So to recap: when you start Gnome Terminal, it starts your shell, and your shell goes through these scripts setting the environment variables.

Comment: It runs whatever is specified by the `SHELL` environment variable.